# Python 3: ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'

Tags: python, module, setup.py

I am working with python 3.3 on a Mac OS X laptop. I have been trying to install the pysparse package, but to no avail.

When running 'python setup.py install', I always get the 'print 'setuptools module not found.'' error. I searched for fixes to this problem and found the threads about the distribute package, which I installed. But this does not change anything and I still get the same error when trying to install the pysparse package.

Has anybody had the same problem or knows how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/1.1.5#unix-based-systems-including-mac-os-x

Comment: How did you install Python? The Python.org binary installer, or a standard install from source, will not include `setuptools`, but many third-party installers, and the packages from most package managers (Homebrew, MacPorts, Fink) may, so the answers will be very different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54331634/no-module-named-setuptools-on-os-x/66621584#66621584

Answer (score 1):

If you have pip installed for python 3.3 then you can install setuptools with `pip-3.3 install setuptools`.

If you don't have pip installed then use `easy_install` to install pip, see [Pip Installation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)

You may want to check you have the right PATHs set in your environment because on Mac python tools tend to get placed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/[2.7,3.3]/bin`

Comment: Hey,thanks for your advice. I just tried this and it tells me, that setuptools is installed. 'sys.path' tells me that I have this: '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.5-py3.3.egg', but I still get the error trying to install pysparse...

Comment: Are you using the right python? `which python` and `python --version`?

Comment: `python --version` gives `Python 3.3.2` when typed in the terminal

Comment: `which python`gave `/opt/local/bin/python`

Comment: Hmm, seems okay. Have you tried `pip-3.3 install pysparse`? Or are there new features not yet committed that you need from source?

Comment: Yeah, this gives `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysparse (from versions: 1.2-dev202, 1.3-dev, 1.1.1-dev, 1.2-dev213, 1.2-dev, 1.2-dev203)` \n `No distributions matching the version for pysparse`

Comment: Okay, just tried it myself... the error isn't in setuptools, the error is a SyntaxError in the `print` statement. It is using the old style `print 'setuptools ...'`. Obviously this package is not built for python-3.x.

Comment: If you have either `easy_install` or `pip`, then you already _have_ `setuptools`, so this answer can't help very much.

Comment: Sorry, was travelling today and couldn't answer earlier. So I guess it's essentially that pysparse is not available for python 3? Would explain a lot. Thank you for the help nonetheless!