# No module named setuptools on OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I tried to install [Auto-Selfcontrol](https://github.com/andreasgrill/auto-selfcontrol) but keep getting the message:"No module named setuptools".

I'm searching around for solutions and end up install setuptools with t[his guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/).

I check the lastest version of setuptools by command:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

And it shows that it's already had the lastest version. However, I'm still getting the message "No module named setuptools" when I try to run setup.py

Is there anything I can do to fix that?

Comment: How did you try to run `setup.py`?

Comment: This commonly happens when more than one version of Python is installed. You confirme that setuptools is present in one of them, but are you sure that you do not use a different version when you get the error?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, I currently have this problem when installing python3. Already try to remove python2 but my terminal still shows version python2 as default when I run `python` in my Terminal. I fix this problem by using command `python3` whenever I use it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I run it by this command `/usr/bin/python setup.py install`

Comment: @SergeBallesta After reading your comment, I try to find the directory of python3 and it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue while installing the package using `brew install`. I checked I had two version of python installed at `/usr/local/Cellar/`. I uninstall python with `brew uninstall python3` and reinstall it again. However, I think just removing one version should work.

if you have Python2 installed, refer to this suggestion [here](https://github.com/tdsmith/homebrew-ham/issues/13)